# Redirect Input & Output of an executable called from a batch file using C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, io-redirection, vivado

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

A simple c# class to send and recieve TCL commands to a Xilinx Vivado application. There is already a built-in TCL shell console within vivado that all it does is to call a batch file (vivado.bat) with a few arguments (-mode tcl). The way this batch file works is as follows:

=== vivado.bat ==

```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    set ... *configure a few environment variables..
    call myBatchFile#1.bat
    set ... *configure a few environment variables..
    call myBatchFile#2.bat
    set ... *configure a few environment variables..
    call myBatchFile#3.bat
    exit
```

where myBatchFile#1.bat and myBatchFile#2.bat set up lots more of environment variables and myBatchFile#3.bat internally calls a 4th batch file (myBatchFile#4.bat) which finally launches the executable file:

=== myBatchFile#4.bat ===

```
    set ... *configure a few environment variables..
    C:/myPathToExe/vivado.exe -mode tcl
    set ... *configure a few more environment variables..
```

**What i've tried so far:**

I came up with the sample code below based on:

1. UseShellExecute must be set to false because I need to redirect both, input and output.
2. Since UseShellExecute is set to false, I can't run batch files directly. As a workaround i run a "cmd.exe" and pass the batch file as an argument.
3. Outputs are stored in a buffer upon output-event firing (newline recieved). Note: output buffer has been defined as a queue to be able to return just 1 line from the buffer or all of them at once (just like a ReadLine, ReadAll methods).

```
    public Process VivadoConsole = new Process();
    private Queue _OutputBuffer = new Queue();
    private string _ErrorBuffer;
    
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.Arguments = "START /b /wait \"vivado\" CMD /s /c \"vivado.bat -mode tcl\"";
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2019.1\bin";
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    VivadoConsole.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    
    VivadoConsole.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
    {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
       {
          _OutputBuffer.Enqueue(e.Data);
       }
    };
    VivadoConsole.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
    {
       _ErrorBuffer += e.Data;
    };
    VivadoConsole.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    
    
    VivadoConsole.Start();
    VivadoConsole.BeginOutputReadLine();
    VivadoConsole.BeginErrorReadLine();
    _OutputBuffer.Clear();
```

**The problem**

No matter what combination of START/CALL/CMD (with the args: /b /c /i /k /wait) I use to launch the "Vivado.bat -mode tcl" file that i can not get my app to work. I know for sure that the output have been redirected properly cause im getting the "splash" text into my outputBuffer variable that the console usually outputs when it loads . But even after that, using

```
    VivadoConsole.StandardInput.WriteLine(str);
```

does nothing. I have noticed that if i do **not redirect** the input and type in directly into the app console window it kind of works (Although i have to type every command twice). To me it looks like redirecting the input from the batch file aint working as expected (I have tried with several combination of endline characters and that didn't work neither)...

Honestly, I dont know what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong but my only other choice would be to manually load every single environment variable and then call the exe file, all from the same console window (though im not sure if that would work ...)

I would prefer any solution that do no require to modify the batch file since it's a 3rd party app. However, if its not possible to do it without actually modifiying the batch file then it will also be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `cmd.exe` arguments must start with `/C`: `VivadoConsole.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C START /b /wait \"vivado\" ...`

Comment: Take c# out of the picture, what happens if you redirect IO from a file within the batch script? Because an application can tell when its input is redirected, you may be SOL.

Comment: Or you might have to use MS's new pseudo console apis (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/).

Comment: *my only other choice would be to manually load every single environment variable and then call the exe file* - seems a better way to me, tbh, and you can use find/replace to turn the batch files into c#, win

Comment: Hi @Aacini,
Adding /C at the beggining of the arguments didn't help at all, same behaviour (i get the "loading" text from the splash screen but whenever i write to it i get no response)...

Comment: Hi @Jeremy,
I just dont know how to redirect IO from a .exe file called from a batch script (into another console, not to a txt nor log file). Based on my crappy sample code i have managed to redirect the output succesfully (kinda) but not so the input. What i have learnt so far is that every batch file called using "CALL" runs in the same environment/window from which its called, howvever, im not sure if that applies to any .exe file called from within that batch file (i guess no)

Comment: Hi @Caius,
I'm afraid that this might be my only choice, though i would prefer to avoid going this route cause if i ever want to switch to a newer version/release i will have to redo all the code again to acomodate for any changes in the script variables and/or code. Hence why a solution to just call the script file and redirect both IO is prefered.

Comment: How much WriteLine'ing do you need to do?